# WebSocketSession.send does not do anything

Tags: java, websocket, spring-webflux

I'm coding a game, when a player end its turn, I want to notify the opponent that it's his turn to play.

So I'm storing WebSocketSessions in "Player" classes, so I just need to get an instance of a player to have access to his websocketsession.

The problem is that nothing is happening when I use the "send" method of a websocketsession stored in a "player" instance.

Here is my code to store a WebSocketSession in a player object, it actually receive properly messages from front end, and it is able to send a message back and it works:

```
@Component("ReactiveWebSocketHandler")
public class ReactiveWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {

        Flux<WebSocketMessage> output = webSocketSession.receive()
                .map(msg -> {
                    String payloadAsText = msg.getPayloadAsText();
                    Account account = authenticationService.getAccountByToken(payloadAsText);
                    Games.getInstance().getGames().get(account.getIdCurrentGame()).getPlayerById(account.getId()).setSession(webSocketSession);
                    return "WebSocketSession id: " + webSocketSession.getId();
                })
                .map(webSocketSession::textMessage);

        return webSocketSession
                .send(output);
    }
}
```

And here is the code I use to notify the opponent player that it is its turn to play, the "opponentSession.send" method seems to produce no result, there is no error message, and it looks like I receive nothing on the front end. The sessions has the same ID than in the handle method so I think the session object is good, also the websocket session was opened and ready when I did my tests:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/game/endTurn", method = RequestMethod.POST)
GameBean endTurn(
        @RequestHeader(value = "token", required = true) String token) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Account account = authenticationService.getAccountByToken(token);
    gameService.endTurn(account);

    Game game = gameService.getGameByAccount(account);
    //GameBean opponentGameBean = game.getOpponentGameState(account.getId());
    //WebSocketMessage webSocketMessage = opponentSession.textMessage(mapper.writeValueAsString(opponentGameBean));
    WebSocketSession opponentSession = game.getPlayerById(game.getOpponentId(account.getId())).getSession();
    WebSocketMessage webSocketMessage = opponentSession.textMessage("test message");

    opponentSession.send(Mono.just(webSocketMessage));

    return gameService.getGameStateByAccount(account);
}
}
```

You can see on the screenshot that the handle method is working correctly, I'm able to send and receive message.
[Websocket input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fkAb.png)

Does someone know how can I make the opponentSession.send method works correctly so that I can receive messages on the front end?

Comment: you should not be mixing webflux and spring web. If you do that, the spring server will boot up a a spring web application, and you will not get the benefits from a reactive application.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the reactive stack for your websocket and [WebSocketSession#send](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/socket/WebSocketSession.html#send-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) return a `Mono<Void>` but you don't subscribe to this Mono (you just assembled it) so nothing will happen until something subscribe to it.

In your endpoint it doesn't look like you are using webflux so you are in synchronous world so you don't have other choice than to `block`

```
opponentSession.send(Mono.just(webSocketMessage)).block();
```

If you are using webflux then you should change your method to return a Mono and do something like:

```java
return opponentSession.send(Mono.just(webSocketMessage)).then(gameService.getGameStateByAccount(account));
```

If you are not familiar with this you should look into [projectreactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/) and [WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

the "block" method caused an error, it is because I'm mixing REST api and webflux I think.

I used:

opponentSession.send(Mono.just(webSocketMessage)).subscribe();

And it worked fine. Thanks a lot for your help, I think I will need to study the reactor project because I'm kinda struggling to understand how reactive programming works.

Comment: The block method can throw an error in some cases. subscribe like this can be an alternative but you might return your GameBean before the webSocketMessage was actually sent